# Uninstallation of a patch uninstall the complete application

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, setup-project, vdproj

Please help on the following scenario.

I have one application installed in my machine. Particular MSI built using Visual Studio .vdproj.
There is a another patch MSI created for the same application by using Visual Studio .vdproj.
The issue is when patch installation fail due to any issue, it will uninstall the complete application.

Can anybody help to diagnosis this issue please?

Answer (score 0):

Applying a patch is actually running the original MSI on maintenance phase and selecting the option to Modify that installation. So in theory if something fails the rollback could remove the entire installation (*however, I never hit such a situation so I cannot say for sure*).

You need to [create a verbose log and have a look around it](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/read-log.html) to see if you spot anything, or share a link for us to look at it?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to explain what you mean by "patch" because there is no support in VS setup projects for building patches, msp files. So did you build a complete new MSI file? Or just an MSI with a few files in it that you want to replace?

If you are really using Visual Studio Setup projects (perhaps with the installer extension) then the only supported upgrade method is to do a RemovePreviousVersions major upgrade. This is old but still accurate, and you must also increment the file versions of any files you want replaced and updated:

https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/updates-to-setup-projects/